# sample C program to add digits from file

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
int  main()
{
    int c=0,d=0;
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("F:\\num.txt" , "r");
    while((c=getw(f1)) != EOF)
    {
        d+=c;
        printf("\n%d",c);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    printf("\n%d",d);
    return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner in files in C. I am trying to find the sum of digits from a file named "num.txt" . The contents in the file is :

```
12486
```

So output should be : `21`
But when I run the code, I don't get the output, instead I get something like:

```
540155953
```

So where is the error in this?

Comment: use `fscanf(f1, "%d", &c)`. The ancient `getw` is for binary files.

Comment: What should this code produce? Is it `12486`? Or is it `21`?

Comment: the file contains 12486 , now I want to get the sum as 21, sum of digits,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't want to use getw. getw read a word not a char.
If you wanto do 1+2+8+4+6, then use :

```
while((c=getc(f1)) != EOF)
    {
        d+=c-48;
        printf("\n%d",c-48);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while((c = fgetc(f1)) != EOF)
{
   num = c - '0';
   d+= num;
}
```

Fetch a character covert it to a integer and than perform addition.

Comment: Thanks , but if I may ask , then what good does the getw() function does? I read it's for integer oriented functions, and is there error in my usage ?

Comment: `getw()` reads `sizeof(int)` bytes from the data stream and stores it as an `int`. It's deprecated in favor of `fread()`. `getw()` would probably work correctly if you had ints written in binary in your file.

Comment: Thanks, It works, Marking this as the answer, btw  , can you suggest me a good book to master these concepts?

Comment: @shanu123 Really if you ask me which book. I don't know, any good online tutorial on file handling will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are using the getw() function which reads the whole word 
you must use getc() which read a single character(not an integer) so you have to convert it into integer then you can perform mathematical calculations in it

```
while(( c= getc(f))!= EOF)
{
    c = c-48;
    d+=c;
    printf("\n%d",c);
}
```

Comment: in this case, if using getc() , should I use a character data_type for the variable for c ?

Comment: no because getc() returns the character which is technically the ascii code (which is in integer form) against that character. the ascii code for '0' to '9' is 48 to 57 respectively, now you see what we done here!!